# pattern.test is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

I really dont understand why the following code doesnt match the regex

```
$val = "12/11/2012";
$opts = {"rule" : "required|format", "format" : {"pattern" : /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/, "errorMsg" : "Invalid date. Allowed allowed: mm/dd/yyyy"}}; 

if(rule=="format" && typeof $opts.format.pattern==="string") {
    try {
       var pattern = (typeof $opts.format.pattern==="object") ? $opts.format.pattern : new Regex($opts.format.pattern, "g");
       if(pattern.test($val)) { // $val contains 12/11/2012
            alert("Invalid Date!"); // Shows invalid format
       }
    } catch(err){
       alert(err.message); // shows pattern.test is not a function
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine when isolated http://jsbin.com/uviwic/2/edit. Problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Try adding to the condition, `if(pattern && !pattern.test($val))`. Maybe the `RegExp` object didn't compile for some reason.

Comment: Do you have a `test` property defined in the `pattern` object already ?

Comment: @adeneo: `pattern` is a `new RegExp`.

Comment: What is `$opts.format.pattern`?  Does the string contain regex delimiters (because it shouldn't)?

Comment: Try `console.log(pattern.test)` and `console.log(RegExp.prototype.test)` to ensure both of those are functions.

Comment: @adeneo there is no test() function already into the object

Comment: I edited the question with $opts content. I was actually trying to validate the string in $val with pattern against $opts.format.pattern

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$opts.format.pattern` is not a string, it's a RegEx object.

So this will work:

```
var $val = "12/11/2012";
var $opts = {"rule" : "required|format", "format" : {"pattern" : /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/, "errorMsg" : "Invalid date. Allowed allowed: mm/dd/yyyy"}}; 

if ($opts.format.pattern instanceof RegExp) {
  try {
    var pattern = $opts.format.pattern;
    if(!pattern.test($val)) {
      alert("Invalid date");
    } else {
      alert("Valid date");
    }
  } catch(err){
    alert(err.message); // shows pattern.test is not a function
  }
}
```